# openFDA API query including "\"

Tags: api, openfda

I came across a question. Some of the generic_name contains backward slash sign, for example, CYCLOPHOSPHAMIDE\PREDNISONE\VINCRISTINE. How to construct the API query that can include backward slash sign?

Answer (score 0):

Those are three separate medication names, not one with backslashes in it. So you would search for them individually or in combinations with logical operators.

For example:

https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.generic_name.exact:%22CYCLOPHOSPHAMIDE%22

Comment: Thank you Denis. So for example, if I would like to search for Aspirin\Prednisolone (means taking Aspirin and Prednisolone at the same time) for a specific indication, the API query could be the following? ... search = (patient.drug.openfda.generic_name.exact:(%22ASPIRIN%22)+AND+patient.drug.openfda.generic_name.exact:(%22PREDNISOLONE%22))+AND+(patient.drug.drugindication.exact: COLITIS)&count=patient.drug.drugindication.exact") ?